# Resizing home and root partions at opensuse

Tags: partition, opensuse, resize2fs

I have divided my ssd into two partitions, one for the root and one for the home directories. Unfortunately I have provided too few space for the root directory and I would like to expand it, by shrinking the home directory.

I have found the [resize2fs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/resize2fs) that it can expand the partition while been in use but I don't have the expertise to complete all the steps without a guide.

Can you provide me with some steps of what to do to shrink the Home partition and expand the root partition without having to format the complete disk?

Comment: As you it sounds like you may not have a lot of experience I would suggest two things.  1. if you dont have any data you care about on your SSD I would just start over and size the partitions correctly this time or. 2 Use a live CD or USB and use the Gparted program to rezise them. It has a nice GUI interface and makes things a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Dylan suggestions to start over, another, non-intrusive option is to move some material from the root partition to the partition for the home directories. You should only do that for non-boot-critical material, but there is a lot of that in `/` outside of `/home`.
My first Unix even had separate partitions for `/usr` and `/var`.

You can copy e.g. everything from `/usr/share` to `/home/ROOT/usr/share` as `root`:

```
cd /usr/share
find . -print0 | cpio -pdmv0 /home/ROOT/usr/share
```

and once that finished correctly do:

```
cd /usr
rm -rf share
ln -s /home/ROOT/usr/share .
```

Newly installed material that goes into `/usr/share` will end up on the `/home` partition. You can of course do multiple subdirectories of `/` in this way, or take a larger chunk by doing one that is higher up the hierarchy.

As long as you don't "move" `/boot` this way you should be fine.